# DDM Probe change settings to stop recording nhttp authentication errors

Tags: ibm-domino

I have gone ahead with standard settings by IBM using the default template to setup DDM, but it's capturing all the failed password attempt on the server by the user, how can I stop those errors from being captured in the DDM, at first glance it wasn't clear which probe needs to be disabled??

Update: DDM was setup for me by an expert admin for us, so I cannot recall whether there is such a thing as a standard template or whether you setup all the probes manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open the reported event in DDM.nsf, you can use the "Triggered by" doclink to get to the probe that generated the event. From there you can disable the probe.